# Can't get `lodash.debounce()` to work properly? Executed multiple times... (react, lodash, hooks)

Tags: reactjs, lodash, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state of a child component in React as the range input moves. And, I want to fire the update function to the parent component's state with Lodash's debounce function so that I don't set the state of the parent component every time range input fires an event.

However, after debounce's delay, all the events are getting fired. As if I called `setTimeout` functions consecutively on every range input event, but not `debounce`.

I can't find what am I missing here. How can I have the function passed into "debounce" get executed once after a series of range input events?

My simplified code looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import React from 'react'

const Form: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const [selectedStorageSize, setSelectedStorageSize] = React.useState(props.storageSize)

    const handleChangeAt = (field, payload) => {
      props.handleFormChangeAt(FormField.InstanceDefs, {
        ...form[FormField.InstanceDefs],
        [field]: payload,
      })
    }

    const debouncedChange = _.debounce(
     (field, payload) => handleChangeAt(field, payload),
     500,
   )

   return(
        <input
          required
          type="range"
          label="Storage Size/GB"
          min={50}
          max={500}
          value={props.selectedStorageSize}
          step={5}
          onChange={e => {
            setSelectedStorageSize(Number(e.target.value))
            debouncedChange(FormField.StorageSize, Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        />
  }
```

Answer (score 22):

#### The Problem

`_.debounce` creates a function that debounces successive calls to the same function instance.  But this is creating a new one every render, so successive calls *aren't* calling the same instance.

You need to reuse the same function across renders.  There's a straightforward way to do that with hooks... and a better way to do it:

#### The straightforward (flawed) solution - `useCallback`

The most straightforward way of preserving things across render is `useMemo`/`useCallback`.  (`useCallback` is really just a special case of `useMemo` for functions)

```js
const debouncedCallback = useCallback(_.debounce(
    (field, payload) => handleChangeAt(field, payload),
    500,
), [handleChangeAt])
```

We've got an issue with `handleChangeAt`: it depends on props and creates a different instance every render, in order to capture the latest version of props.  If we only created `debouncedCallback` once, we'd capture the first instance of `handleChangeAt`, and capture the initial value of `props`, giving us stale data later.

We fix that by adding `[handleChangeAt]`, to recreate the `debouncedCallback` whenever `handleChangeAt` changes.  However, as written, `handleChangeAt` changes *every* render.  So this change alone won't change the initial behavior: we'd still recreate `debouncedCallback` every render.  So you'd need to memoize `handleChangeAt`, too:

```js
const { handleFormChangeAt } = props;
const handleChangeAt = useCallback((field, payload) => {
    handleFormChangeAt(/*...*/)
}, [handleFormChangeAt]);
```

(If this sort of memoizing isn't familiar to you, I highly recommend Dan Abramov's [Complete Guide to `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), even though we aren't actually using `useEffect` here)

This pushes the problem up the tree, and you'll need to make sure that whatever component provides `props.handleFormChangeAt` is also memoizing it.  But, otherwise this solution *largely* works...

#### The better solution - `useRef`

Two issues with the previous solution: as mentioned it pushes the problem of memoization up the tree (specifically because you're depending on a function passed as a prop), but the whole point of this is so that we can recreate the function whenever we need to, to avoid stale data.

But the recreating to avoid stale data is going to cause the function to be recreated, which is going to cause the debounce to reset: so the result of the previous solution is something that *usually* debounces, but might not, if props or state have changed.

A better solution requires us to really only create the memoized function once, but to do so in a way that avoids stale data.  We can do that by using a ref:

```js
const debouncedFunctionRef = useRef()
debouncedFunctionRef.current = (field, payload) => handleChangeAt(field, payload);

const debouncedChange = useCallback(_.debounce(
    (...args) => debouncedFunctionRef.current(...args),
    500,
), []);
```

This stores the current instance of the function to be debounced in a ref, and updates it every render (preventing stale data).  Instead of debouncing that function directly, though, we debounce a wrapper function that reads the current version from the ref and calls it.

Since the only thing the callback depends on is a ref (which is a constant, mutable object), it's okay for `useCallback` to take `[]` as its dependencies, and so we'll only debounce the function once per component, as expected.

#### As a custom hook

This approach could be moved into its own custom hook:

```js
const useDebouncedCallback = (callback, delay) => {
    const callbackRef = useRef()
    callbackRef.current = callback;
    return useCallback(_.debounce(
        (...args) => callbackRef.current(...args),
        delay,
    ), []);
};
```

```js
const { useCallback, useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const useDebouncedCallback = (callback, delay, opts) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef()
  callbackRef.current = callback;
  return useCallback(_.debounce(
      (...args) => callbackRef.current(...args),
      delay,
      opts
  ), []);
};

function Reporter({count}) {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("Click to record the count")
  const onClick = useDebouncedCallback(() => {
    setMsg(`The count was ${count} when you clicked`);
  }, 2000, {leading: true, trailing: false})
  return <div>
    <div><button onClick={onClick}>Click</button></div>
    {msg}
    </div>
}

function Parent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setCount(x => x+1), 500)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <div>The count is {count}</div>
      <Reporter count={count} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: I really appreciate your long explanation Restam, it took a while to wrap my head around your explanation. However, this doesn't help the problem - I tried your structure and confirmed it doesn't work for me. Your code snippet here works perfectly because you are missing 2 crucial things from my problem:

1. I am trying to update `Parent` 's state with debounce, but my `input` 's  `value` attribute reads from the `child` 's state (updated parallel to the parent's state by a hook).

2. My input is a `range` input, not a text or button input.

Comment: For your code snippet, try to make it like this: 
Replace the button with a range input, set the UI input value in Reporter's state and read from there and show on the screen, but at the same time, set the same value on the Parent component's state "with a debounce" and show that on the screen, as well. That is my problem.

Comment: I tried the first two solutions proposed here and they didn't work, plus the explanation was a bit tricky to understand.  In the end `useMemo` was the way to go in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

I used `useCallback` with `_.debounce`, but faced with a eslint error, 'React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.'

Finally, I found [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19240), and used `useMemo`.

before:

```
 const debouncedMethod = useCallback(
    debounce((arg) => {
      someMethod(arg);
    }, 500),
    [someMethod],
  );
```

after:

```
  const debouncedMethod = useMemo(
    () =>
      debounce((arg) => {
        someMethod(arg);
      }, 500),
    [someMethod],
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

[lodash.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) creates a new function invocations of which will be debounced. Use case scenario is creating it once, storing result in a variable and calling it multiple times so the calls get debounced. You are creating a new debounced function every time you render a component so every new render you get a new debounce scope

You want to call `const debouncedChange = _.debounce(...)` only once per component instance. I am not very much familiar with hooks, but guess you can do this

```
const [debouncedChange] = React.useState(_.debounce(
    (field, payload) => handleChangeAt(field, payload),
    500,
))
```

this will create your function once during render and reuse what's created across successive renders

Comment: hmm, but, in my code `const debounceChange = _.debounce(...)` is already a variable since this is a functional component and it is being created only once, already, isn't it?

Comment: Your diagnosis of the issue is correct, but the actual solution with hooks is more complex.

Comment: @Retsam can you share your solution if you know how to implement deboounce using hooks, please?

Comment: nope, functional component's body runs every time component renders. Some parts of code run only once (i.e. evaluating initial value for a state variable, or special cases of `useEfffect`) but that's just React magic behind the scenes. Rest of the code runs as usual @Ege